# Python - Get Instagram API Access Token

Tags: python, instagram-api

I am trying to call the Instagram Basic API to get the user info. However, I need to fetch the access token first for the authentication.

I have implemented the code for getting the same in python but I am only able to fetch the re-direct uri. Now, as a manual step we execute that uri on browser and get the code from the url.

But in case of programming how can I get the access token?

In below code: I am getting error

```
from instagram_basic_display.InstagramBasicDisplay import InstagramBasicDisplay
from flask import request


instagram_basic_display = InstagramBasicDisplay(app_id='5163403347035424', app_secret='80473de6ad506c837969e03b8ccdb4cb', redirect_url='https://mycogito.me/')

print(instagram_basic_display.get_login_url()) # Returns login URL you need to follow

code = request.args.get('code')
print(code)
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Work Backup\Development\Workspaces\python\SocialMedia\src\com\social\media\HelloWorld.py", line 9, in <module>
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=5163403347035424&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmycogito.me%2F&scope=user_profile%2Cuser_media&response_type=code
    code = request.args.get('code')
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 347, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 306, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\globals.py", line 38, in _lookup_req_object
    raise RuntimeError(_request_ctx_err_msg)
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.
```

Comment: This [repo](https://github.com/arc298/instagram-scraper) maybe a worthy example for using the Instagram API in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

There is a package when you want to get data from instagram and written in python [click](https://github.com/realsirjoe/instagram-scraper).